# (discord js) Why my bot can't execute the same command (it takes time to complete) 2 times at the same time?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm new to discord js. I have a "hack" command that (it is a joke command) it "hacks" the person you tag. `(prefix)hack @user`

Here is the code:

```
 execute(message, args){

        function wait(ms){
            let start = new Date().getTime();
            let end = start;
            while(end < start + ms) {
              end = new Date().getTime();
           }
         }

        const taggedUser = message.mentions.users.first();
        if (taggedUser.bot) {
            return message.channel.send('People live and learn... but you just live');
        }
        message.channel.send(`Hacking  ${taggedUser}...`);
        message.channel.send('Status: 0%')
        .then(msg => {
            wait(93);
            msg.edit('Status: 7%');
            wait(100);
            msg.edit('Status: 8%');
            wait(20)
            msg.edit('Status: 9%');
            wait(90);
            msg.edit('Status: 12%');
            wait(60);
            msg.edit('Status: 14%');
            wait(60);
            msg.edit('Status: 17%');
            wait(40);
            msg.edit('Status: 20%');
            wait(10);
            msg.edit('Status: 21%');
            wait(12);
            msg.edit('Status: 22%');
            wait(13);
            msg.edit('Status: 24%');
            wait(80);
            msg.edit('Status: 29%');
            wait(80);
            msg.edit('Status: 31%');
            wait(80);
            msg.edit('Status: 36%');
            wait(40);
            msg.edit('Status: 41%');
            wait(60);
            msg.edit('Status: 47%');
            wait(50);
            msg.edit('Status: 53%');
            wait(35);
            msg.edit('Status: 58%');
            wait(80);
            msg.edit('Status: 66%');
            wait(60);
            msg.edit('Status: 74%');
            wait(20);
            msg.edit('Status: 79%');
            wait(83);
            msg.edit('Status: 80%');
            wait(50);
            msg.edit('Status: 85%');
            wait(14);
            msg.edit('Status: 93%');
            wait(70);
            msg.edit('Status: 97%');
            wait(90);
            msg.edit('Status: 100%').then(() => {
                message.channel.send(`Succesfuly hacked ${taggedUser}.\n**I just sent you a text file to your DM with his IP and the password to remotly control his computer**`);
            })
        })
    },
```

The problem is that when I try to hack two persons at the same time (I send two times the command), it starts changing the status of the first one but the second one doesn't start changing until the other one reaches 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You might have gotten rate limited for editing too many messages too fast.

I suppose you should make those delay longer, or edit the messages a little bit less

Answer (score 0):

What about making the whole message edit part asynchronous ? I feel like those messages aren't editing themselves at the right time, and that making use of `async / await` could fix your problem.